# Validation onfocus on the label text and input border

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript, I have input validation, when it's empty and click outside the input, it shows an error or red color on the border and label input. When it's onfocus, click inside the input or adding text, the border becomes blue and the label text should follow the same as the input color.

I tried to add onfocus inside the input function so it triggers the validation on the label text, however it doesn't seem to work, please advice.

```js
      const userInput = document.querySelectorAll(".inputJs");
const userLabel = document.querySelectorAll(".guestlist-form-label");

      userInput.forEach(function(evt, index) {
        evt.onblur = function() {
          const textInput = userLabel[index];

          if (evt.value === "") {
            evt.classList.add("has-error");
            textInput.classList.add("has-error");
          } else {
            evt.classList.remove("has-error");
            textInput.classList.remove("has-error");
          }
        };

        userLabel.onfocus = function() {
          const textLabel = userLabel[index];

          if (userLabel.classList.contains("has-error")) {
            textLabel.classList.remove("has-error");
            textLabel.classList.add("has-blue");
          } else {
            textLabel.classList.remove("has-blue");
          }
        };
      });
```

```css
.guestlist-form-label.has-blue {
  color: blue;
}

.guestlist-form-label.has-error {
  color: red;
}

.inputJs.has-error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 62%;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 48%;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input label {
  color: #9b9b9b;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #4990e2;
  color: #4990e2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(73, 144, 226, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(73, 144, 226, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<form id="app" class="guestlist-form-wrapper">
        <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
          <label class="guestlist-form-label">First Name *</label>
          <input type="text" class="inputJs">
        </div>
        <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
          <label class="guestlist-form-label">Last Name *</label>
          <input type="text" class="inputJs">
        </div>
        <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
          <label class="guestlist-form-label">Email *</label>
          <input type="email" class="inputJs">
        </div>
        <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
          <label class="guestlist-form-label">Phone *</label>
          <input type="tel" class="inputJs">
        </div>

      </form>
```

Comment: SO your code says on focus.... if the error class is there remove it. If it is not add it? The focus is not doing any validation like the blur does.

Comment: @epascarello yes, onfocus, if the error class there, then it would remove the error class, if the error class is not there, then it would add focus, I just edit my code to add the css and the selector.

Comment: Why are you adding an error class if it is not there on focus? The else makes no sense. Or maybe I do not understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @epascarello Because when the input is empty, the label text should have error red text, that's the reason I'm adding the error class, when it's onfocus, the label text becomes blue.

Comment: But it is not checking if it is empty, it is just looking at a class. `if (userLabel.classList.contains("has-error")) { .... } else { textLabel.classList.add("has-error"); }` <-- I do not understand that adding....

Comment: @epascarello I tried to remove the error class, but doesn't make any different, the label text is still red when it's focus, instead of blue, nb: I just edit my code, sorry for confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You over complicated the focus. Just remove the error classes.

```js
const userInput = document.querySelectorAll(".inputJs");
const userLabel = document.querySelectorAll(".guestlist-form-label");

userInput.forEach(function(input, index) {
  const labelInput = userLabel[index];
  const errorClass = 'has-error'
  const blueClass = 'has-blue'
  input.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    var hasError = input.value === ""
    input.classList.toggle(errorClass, hasError);
    labelInput.classList.toggle(errorClass, hasError);
    labelInput.classList.remove(blueClass);  
  });
  input.addEventListener("focus", function () {
    input.classList.remove(errorClass);
    labelInput.classList.remove(errorClass);  
    labelInput.classList.add(blueClass);  
  })
});
```

```css
.guestlist-form-label.has-blue {
  color: blue;
}

.guestlist-form-label.has-error {
  color: red;
}

.inputJs.has-error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 62%;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 48%;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input label {
  color: #9b9b9b;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.guestlist-form-wrapper-input input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #4990e2;
  color: #4990e2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(73, 144, 226, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(73, 144, 226, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<form id="app" class="guestlist-form-wrapper">
  <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
    <label class="guestlist-form-label">First Name *</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputJs">
  </div>
  <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
    <label class="guestlist-form-label">Last Name *</label>
    <input type="text" class="inputJs">
  </div>
  <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
    <label class="guestlist-form-label">Email *</label>
    <input type="email" class="inputJs">
  </div>
  <div class="guestlist-form-wrapper-input">
    <label class="guestlist-form-label">Phone *</label>
    <input type="tel" class="inputJs">
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Respecting your style, change

```
userLabel.onfocus = function() {
  const textLabel = userLabel[index];

  if (userLabel.classList.contains("has-error")) {
    textLabel.classList.remove("has-error");
    textLabel.classList.add("has-blue");
  } else {
    textLabel.classList.remove("has-blue");
  }
};
```

to

```
evt.onfocus = function() {
    userLabel[index].classList.remove("has-error");
};
```

I am upvoting @epascarello answer.